# How to use MongoDB with mean.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, mean.io

I am new to server side javascipt. I have started with mean.io. I gained some understanding of nodejs, express, mongodb last few days. I have my mean.io app but I don't know what's the right way to connect to mongodb and query it from my js files.
Is there a guide/blog which can help me work with mongodb from my server side javascript files?
All I want is to store some data mongodb and fetch that at some later point.

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I have just created the meanio app from the doc in mean.io. I am parsing a rss feed. I want to store that data into mongodb.

Comment: there is multiple multiple tutorials on this, have you bothered googling this?

Comment: There are many related to mongodb, nodejs & express but I am looking for the one related to mean.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find one related to mean.io but below few links helped me get started with mean.io.

http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/node-express-mongo/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEE7DY2AYvI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5e1NEdfs4is

**Edit:**
Past few days I have been working on it and by test & learn I was able to got things working for me. I'll share whatever I know till now.

- So mean.io use `mongoose` ODM to connect to the mongodb.
- `mean.io` would automatically connect to your DB. You can configure DB name in `development.js` `db: 'mongodb://localhost/myDB'`. So you won't have to worry about connecting to mongoDB. You just need to start the mongoDB using `mongod`.

**How to use mongoose?**

To use `mongoose` to connect to mongoDB you need to build schemas. You can do so in  `myApp/app/models` directory, since they represents models.

Sample model file `user.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  
var userSchema = new Schema({  
    name: String,
    email: String,
    DOB  : Date,
    address: {  
              house_no: String,  
              street: String  
             }  
});  

module.exports = mongoose.model('tbl_user',userSchema);
```

Note:- `tbl_user` would be stored as `tbl_userS` in DB.

**How to save data to mongoDB?**

One would generally do `save` to DB in controller. Below I have shown how one can do this.
To make models available to all controller one need to write this piece of code in server.js so that all your models get registered during server startup. Alternatively, import individual models using `require('tbl_user')`.

`Server.js` :-

```
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models';
    var arrFiles = fs.readdirSync(models_path);
    arrFiles.forEach(function(file){
        if(file.indexOf('.js') > 0){
            require(models_path + '/' + file);
        }

    });
```

controller code `myApp/app/controllers/myController.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jsonEntry = {'name':'Mady', 'email':'xyz@xyz.com', 'address':{'house_no':12N, 'stree':'abc'}};
var User = mongoose.model('tbl_user');
var user = new User(jsonEntry);
user.save();
```

The above code would create and update the `tbl_users` collection in mongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

By default, you should see there is a `mean-dev` collection in your mongodb. The best way I thought to get familiar with mongo and mean is play around the code (for instance, the article package). Inside `/packages/article/system/`, you will see how the blog example works.

That works great for me.

Comment: this is now `meanStarter` package